# How to run gulp task with watch ONLY if a new file was added

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

> This question is asked on gulp 3.8.10, using gulp.watch not 'gulp-watch'

I have a task that injects all my html/css/js files into my index.html

```
gulp.task('index', function () {
  var sources = gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js', './src/**/*.css'], {read: false});
  return gulp.src('./src/index.html')
    .pipe(inject(sources, {ignorePath: 'src', addRootSlash: false }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src'));
});
```

This task is triggered automatically by :

```
gulp.watch('src/**/*', ['index']);
```

Since all this task does is, import external files to my index.html like so :

```
<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="module/module.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
```

**I would like to *only* have the watcher run this task if a new file was ADDED**, it does not make sense to re-run and modify my index.html file, when i simply change a file that's already injected in there.

Is there a way to do this with gulp ?

**Edit:** **after accepting the answer** here is the actual code that worked for my given example :

```
gulp.watch('src/**/*', function(event) {
  if (event.type === 'added' ) {
    gulp.start('index');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the task or callback, you'll have an `event` parameter, which has a `type` property, which will tell you if the file was added, deleted or changed.  Best bet is probably to make use of that in a conditional on your task.

```
function watcher(event){
   if(event.type === 'added'){ /* do work */ }
}
```

Comment: So in the task above I used gulp.task('index', function (event) { , but event seems to be a function, and if i don't call it, gulp exits on the task. Is that what you meant ? add the event parameter to the function that gets ran by the task ? Because it doesn't seem to have a type ( console.log(event.type) prints undefined, while console.log(event) prints [Function].

Comment: No, not in the task, but in the callback from watch. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob-opts-cb  . Edited for clarity.

Comment: for some reason the code in your latest edit does not work for me. I did get it working with the code suggested in your link above. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, rolled back, then.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for anyone that gets here from Google, the syntax has changed for Gulp 4. You should instead do the following:

```
gulp.watch('src/**/*', {events: ['add']}, gulp.series('index'));
```

reference: https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch#options